# Completing a user's name when pinging on the Stack Overflow app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, user-experience, stack-overflow-app

I sometimes ask or answer a question using the Stack Overflow app and sometimes there is a comment I want to reply to (IE I want to ping).  In my browser I can ping with `@` and you get something like this:

[image]

however on the Stack Overflow app it does not allow me to do this.  I enter `@` and nothing happens and am therefore often forced to switch to my browser to use this convenient feature.  Can we have a feature that allows us to complete the username when pinging on the Stack Overflow app?

Comment: AFAIK writing `@SomeUserName` manually will still get that user notified once you post the comment.

Comment: it's probably a difference in versions as you've tagged the android app but the iOS app when you do that has a list of pingable usernames just above the comment box your trying in

Comment: @Memor-X  Mine doesn't.  Do you think it may be outdated?

Comment: @E_net4 Yes but typing somthing like: `@user192684` is a bit unnecessary and quite likely to get it wrong.

Comment: @Simon I am not opposed to that. It just sounds that the question should be asking about auto-completing a user name in a comment rather than pinging a user on the SO app.

Comment: @Simon if it's the iOS one i would believe so and it would be easy to update. no experience with Android with out it updates or if there's any difference between it and the iOS version (logically there shouldn't but who knows?)

Comment: @Memor-X. Yes it's the Android version.

Comment: @E_net4 I've edited as you suggested.  I was asking that.  Sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Stack Exchange & Stack Overflow Android app, there's no username autocomplete when you write on the comment box. Instead, you can select which comment you want to reply:

1. Select a comment
2. Tap the "Reply" button (curved-left arrow)
3. The comment box will automatically add `@username`

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Very clear, well written answer.Thank you very much.  I've been typing it out manually ever since I've got the app this is going to save me a lot of hassle.